# How to add a focus handler to all <input>'s and <select>'s within a <form>

Tags: jquery

This is my code for applying a focus handler to all `<input>`'s within a `<form>`. I also want to apply this code to `<select>`'s within the `<form>` too?

There are other elements within the `<form>` that I don't want to match, like `<divs>` and `<span>`s.

```
$('#appform').on({
    'focus': function () {
        // do something
    }
}, 'input');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the selector to use `,`:

```
$('#appform').on({...}, 'input');
```

Should be:

```
$('#appform').on({...}, 'input,select');
```

Official docs: [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

So yours is a combination of the [element selector](https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) and the multiple selector. As another example, the selector `taga,tagb` matches all elements of tag `<taga>` **OR** `<tagb>`.